# What is the difference between "in style" and "with style"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I'm confused about whether to use "in style" or "with style" after a verb. Is it correct to say both, and if it is, is there a difference between the two expressions?

For instance, for a slogan, I was thinking of something like

> Do it with style

or

> Do it in style

According to [this post](https://www.italki.com/post/question-297710) and a few google searches, it seems that "in style" is more correct, but I've also seen "with style" being used quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In style" primarily means that something is *currently fashionable*. For example, you might say that a particular item of clothing is "in style".

"With style" typically means that some thought, design, or flair has been put into something. For example, if you do something 'with style' it may be impressive, or look good. Note also that the expression "with style" is sometimes used humorously if something is unexpectedly a spectacle - for example, if someone fell over in an exaggerated or embarrassing way, perhaps knocking things over, someone might say they fell over "with style".

Answer (score 1):

***In style*** is an idiomatic phrase. ***With style*** is not.
The [FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+style) defines the idiom ***in style*** as:

> In a luxurious or glamorous way. Trendy or fashionable. In a striking or outstanding manner. In this usage, an adjective (such as "*great*" or "*fine*") can be used before "*style*."

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/style_1) gives an example of ***with style*** where the preposition *with* is combined with *style* when it is used with a particular meaning:

> an attractive or impressive way of behaving or doing something
> *with style*:

> - I was greeted with great style.

[Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20style%2C%20with%20style&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20style%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20style%3B%2Cc0) shows that *in style* is more common than *with style*, but it may be argued that these are different meaning which should not be compared.

I understand ***in style*** as meaning ***in a stylish/elegant way***, whereas ***with style*** - ***in an impressive way***.

Comment: "In style" does **not** mean "in a stylish way".

Comment: Well, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20style#:~:text=1%20%3A%20popular%20or%20fashionable,to%20do%20it%20in%20style.) disagrees with you: _in a way that is impressive or admired because it shows talent, good taste, etc. : **in a stylish way**_. I would recommend you argue with them and retract your DV.

Comment: MW is primarily an American English dictionary. We call it 'Wobsters' here in the UK because of how much it varies from every other dictionary. Do you have any other references?

Comment: There was no specification that the answer should or should not be concerned with a certain type of English. I think M-W should not be dismissed just because you are used to something different.

Comment: the problem with Ngrams is that they reflect only what is found in a limited selection of written English. They don't prove what is actually more commonly *spoken*. Nor do they account for *how* these expressions are used in the context. Your link to MW relies on the *secondary* meaning of 'in style', so likely the ngram results are being skewed by the primary use.